# execute immediate a pl/sql that having execute immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have a query string that have execute immediate.

how can I Execute Immediate this PL/SQL?

**query string** = 'Execute immediate select ....';

Want do this: `Execute immediate 'query string';`

That became this: `Execute immediate  'Execute immediate select ....;';`

Do you know How can I do this?

Comment: A more complete example would be useful. Your 'query string' is missing internal single quotes; and does that exist in a variable? What are you going to do with the results of the query?

Answer (score 5):

Without commenting on whether it is normal or wise: yes, I believe you can do it.  That is, I've never seen anything written about `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` that suggested it is not re-entrant.  Plus, it works if you try it.

Here is a simple, typical `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` call:

```
DECLARE
  l_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :l_count FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE ROWNUM <= 100' INTO l_count;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('l_count = ' || l_count);
END;
```

Here is basically the same thing, but with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` calls nested to two levels:

```
DECLARE
  l_outer_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'!
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :x FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE ROWNUM <= 100' INTO :l_outer_count;
END;
!'
USING IN OUT l_outer_count;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_outer_count = ' || l_outer_count);
END;
```

I have never encountered a need to do this.

Comment: If we have some parameter that maybe contain 1 parameter or maybe 3 parameters  how to do this pl/sql with using?

Comment: I want do this: `declare m  varchar2(1000) := 'SELECT description  FROM TB1 WHERE  id= :z';       u number := 5;  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '||m||'  INTO :l_outer_count using '|| u || '; `

Comment: Dynamically constructing a PL/SQL block to handle variations in numbers of bind variables makes perfect sense. I am not sure, though, why you would need to do an execute immediate inside an execute immediate. You are constructing your block of code at run time. Why would you need to do dynamic SQL inside a dynamically constructed string?